# Motivation for Clone Objects

Tags: c#, clone

When to use Clone (not the definition please)? I can initiate an object and use the object so why to use clone in the real world?

What is the motivation for shallow clone (I know that it copies the value types and make a reference to the the reference type) ?

please give me an examples from the real world and not the definition of clone,deep clone or shallow clone.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> please give me an examples from the real world

If you have an object that's not thread safe but you can clone it to multiple independent instances you can then use those individual instances on different threads.

Answer (score 1):

> please give me an examples from the real world

One Example which I used some days ago:

I developed a component for printing different kind of documents based on a third party component.

In my context this is a complex construction and not "cheap" and "easy" to instantiate. Sometimes I need more than one printing-component. So use a shallow clone and only replace the config-object ("sub-objects" of printing-component which provides all printing relevant environment informations) gives me what I need with lees amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

An example could be, You might want to preserve your current object values and upon some condition you might want to rollback back to previous value. Think of settings for an application. In the settings window you might press cancel or save. If you press cancel you need to discard all changes. so you clone settings object, show it to the user and if pressed save simply get values from cloned object and set to real object